# Leetcode House Robber submission vs custom testcase

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am working on the [198. House Robber](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/) LeetCode Problem:

> You are a professional robber planning to rob houses along a street. Each house has a certain amount of money stashed, the only constraint stopping you from robbing each of them is that adjacent houses have security systems connected and **it will automatically contact the police if two adjacent houses were broken into on the same night.**
>
> Given an integer array `nums` representing the amount of money of each house, return the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight **without alerting the police**.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3,1]
> Output: 4
> ```
>
> **Explanation:** Rob house 1 (money = 1) and then rob house 3 (money = 3).
> Total amount you can rob = 1 + 3 = 4.
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [2,7,9,3,1]
> Output: 12
> ```
>
> **Explanation:** Rob house 1 (money = 2), rob house 3 (money = 9) and rob house 5 (money = 1).
> Total amount you can rob = 2 + 9 + 1 = 12.

#### My code

```py
class Solution:
    def rob(self, nums, n=0, memo={}):
        if n in memo:
            return memo[n]
        
        if n == len(nums) - 1:
            return nums[n]
        if n > len(nums) - 1:
            return 0
        
        f = nums[n] + self.rob(nums, n + 2)
        s = nums[n + 1] + self.rob(nums, n + 3)
        
        memo[n] = max(f, s)

        return max(f, s)
```

When I click the submit button it fails with input: `[2,7,9,3,1]`. But when I run it as a custom testcase it seems to work:

[image: Two screenshots]

Comment: What is the point of `memo={}`?

Comment: You are not passing down the `memo` dictionary in the recursive calls.

Comment: @PéterLeéh: Of course he is. This is a case of the mutable default argument.

Comment: @quamrana Oops, I missed it. I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `memo` parameter.

As it is defined (`memo={}`) it will never be reset between test cases, and so it will carry values that have nothing to do with the current test case.

Unlike in other languages, default values for parameters are only evaluated at the time of function *definition*, not *execution*.

So make sure to define `memo` as local variable inside your function, not as an argument.

You can create a recursive function as a *nested* function inside `rob`, so to have access to the same instance of `memo` during recursion.

So alter your code to this:

```
def rob(self, nums):
    memo = {}  # define here so it gets reset at every call
    
    def recur(n):  # recursive function with access to memo
        if n in memo:
            return memo[n]

        if n == len(nums) - 1:
            return nums[n]
        if n > len(nums) - 1:
            return 0

        f = nums[n] + recur(n + 2)
        s = nums[n + 1] + recur(n + 3)

        memo[n] = max(f, s)

        return max(f, s)
    
    return recur(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where I constantly update the elements and find the max sum according to the rules:

```
class Solution:
    def rob(self, nums):
        if len(nums) == 1:
            return nums[0]

        elif len(nums) == 2:
            return max(nums[0], nums[1])

        else:
            robFirst = nums[0]
            robSecond = max(nums[0], nums[1])

            for i in range(2, len(nums)):
                current = max(robSecond, robFirst + nums[i])

                robFirst = robSecond
                robSecond = current

        return robSecond
```